# Angular Material and the Safari Browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, safari, material-design, angular-material

I noticed that Safari doesn't work well with Angular Material. It looks like compatibility issues are everywhere: styles, layout, etc. Has anyone else faced those issues and have good advice on how to workaround those things nicely?

Comment: Same here - I am seeing issues in Safari that are not even present in IE, let alone FF or Chrome. Prominently, we are having lots of cases of `md-content` collapsing (height: 0) for apparently no good reason at all, completely hiding whole layout sections etc.

Comment: it seems that it's the `layout-fill` attribute specifically. The `height:100%` is what causes the collapsing issues in Safari.

Comment: This case issue: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/1720 seemed to help me a lot with the layout for safari

Comment: Have you upgraded to the latest release of Angular Material? I'm using 1.0.4 and not seeing these issues.

Comment: @dim0_0n Are you using hard **css resets**? I had similar issues with Firefox and that helped some.

Comment: angular material is not supported for IE9, safari and some old firefox browsers. we cant do anything  about it. best way to bypass this, by using alternate js or custom classes for those unsupported browsets/

Comment: I recently had issues when using `layout="column"`,  all the heights of the elements were collapsing to 0px, it looked like a mess,  I had to remove layout and do it with only css.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question if you don't have a specific issue. I've been able to produce multiple angular material applications that work consistently across multiple devices and browsers. For example for @alicona 's issue I used `layout-column` on the parent and then the child would be a `layout-row layout-wrap` and that worked pretty well. For `md-content` not being a scrollable area or collapsing you may have to wrap an `md-content` inside another `md-content`...

Comment: Some of my issue got solved with the help of Polyfill js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of the question, there were indeed problems with Angular Material in Safari:

- layout (mostly flex-related issues)
- dialogs (positions calculated wrongly / dialogs collapsed)
- performance (some of the fancy animations, including ripple, scale from click coords, etc)

You were using Angular Material at version < `v0.10.1`, which in fact had a lot of problems in general. However, nowadays (and in fact after Angular Material `v1.x`), those problems are gone (not only in Safari).

Angular Material became more stable and more performant (proof of this are the 7000+ closed issues). Flexbox is also better supported nowadays, which was the cause of many layout issues for versions < 1.x.

*For anybody finding the question today that is running Angular Material < `v1.x`*, **the answer is simple: upgrade Angular Material to a newer version, preferably `v1.1+`.**

Comment: Down voted because this is currently not a solution. Angular material is still broken in Safari as of v6.4.0.

Comment: still having issues with tabs in ^10.2.7

Comment: safari/angular cli 8.3.29/material 8.2.3, well advanced past the expected point of compatibility

Answer (score 0):

I am using angular material https://material.angular.io in package.json version is "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.12" and its work fine in crome browser but style/layout/font are break in safari browser V 5.1.7(7534.57.2).
here is screenshots of some sample control[image]